# How to search imported CSV cell values for each row

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I'm attempting to import a csv, search the cell values(columns) in each row and then find and count any null or blank values. Then if the count hits 13, do X. However, when I run this code it appears the cell/column values are a single object and not the individual values for each column? How can I search the individual cell values in the row?

SAMPLE CODE

```
$DataFileLocation = "\\Server\Output.csv"
$sheet = import-csv $DataFileLocation
$count = 0
foreach ($row in $sheet) {
    foreach ($column in $row) {
        Write-Host "Searching value: $column"
        if ($column -eq $null -or " ") {
            Write-Host "Found a blank!"
            $count++
        }
    }
    $count
    if ($count -eq 13) {
        Write-Host "Found match!" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    $count = 0
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each `$row` is a [`PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0):

```
PS > $row.GetType().Name
PSCustomObject
```

Access the underlying property values:

```
foreach ($column in $row.psobject.Properties.Value){
...
}
```

Check if `$column` is `$null`, empty or white space:

```
if ([System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($column)) { ... }
```

Comment: That appears to have worked, thank you! However, I did run into an error "system.outofmemoryException". Likely because my data set is so huge, any ideas on how to address this without splitting up the original file? One other thing (bonus points) how can I export the results to a csv and have it be in the same format e.g. same column headers and then append each row?

Comment: Forgot to mention the outofmemoryexception occurs when I import the csv. It's like 500 MB, it's a beast.

Comment: Good news, I switched to the 64 bit version and that solved the memory exception issue. Now just to export the data back into a csv format. =)

Comment: before the `foreach` loop define your output array, ex `$outputsheet = @()`
In the loop `if ($count -eq 13) {$outputsheet += $row}`
After the loop `$outputsheet | Export-Csv "\\Server\Outputsheet.csv"`

Answer (score 1):

Or something like

```
$DataFileLocation = "\\Server\Output.csv"
$sheet = import-csv $DataFileLocation
$count = 0
foreach ($row in $sheet){
  ($row | Get-Member) | ? { $_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty" } | % { 
    $n = $_.Name; "$n = $($row."$n")" 
  }
}
```

Comment: I voted for @nas but this was my feeble attempt before his post was visible.